# visiting facebook profile after clicking facebook like button

Tags: php, facebook-like

Normal facebook like api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ if you include it in your web page just allows you to like that page and do nothing else . Is there any way where in I can open home page of person linking that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer facebook has something called as edge.create event (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) with help of this i can redirect it to that persons home page